# Button that displays and hides a sliding menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm trying to build a header with a menu button that triggers a sliding menu. I can make the menu appear when I press the button, but I also want it to dissappear when I click the button again.

This is the event that triggers when the button is clicked.

```
$('#nav-button').click(function () {

    $("#slidermenu").animate({right: "0px"}, 200);

    $("body").animate({right: "300px"}, 200);    

});
```

I looked up the animate method and saw that it has a function called **done**, which takes two parameters. A promise and a boolean. So I figured I can use a **if-statement** to check if the animation is done, and if the animation is done, the button would send the slidermenu back.

But how can I test if animate().done() is true? Or  is there a more simple way of achiveing this?

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1rrhp3ps/3/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.is(':animated')` will return `true` if it's currently being animated.

In the context of what you're trying to do:

```
if(!$('#slidermenu').is(':animated'))
{
  // Animation has finished
}
```

*As an aside:*

I try and do this with CSS only now where possible. If you use jQuery `toggleClass` and predefine the `right` attributes in your CSS for the toggled classes, you can add a CSS transition to deal with the animation. Just thought it was worth mentioning (this does come with it's own compatibility issues).

Comment: Thank you very much! Will try this out in css.

Answer (score 1):

Like DeeMac said, it may be better to do this with `css transition` instead of `jQuery animate`. But just to add an option, I'll try to show you how to get this to work with `jQuery animation` also.

First of all, instead of inspecting if the animation is still running or not, you can just `stop` the ongoing animation before starting another. It will make the button to respond immediately to the users clicks.

For finding out if the menu is open or not, you can use `toggleClass`. This way you can just use `hasClass` to determine in which direction you need to animate the menu.

So, this what I came up with:

```
$('#nav-button').click(function () {
    $("#slidermenu").stop();

    animateToPosition = "0px";
    if ($("#slidermenu").hasClass("open")) {
        animateToPosition = "-300px";
    }

    $("#slidermenu").toggleClass("open");

    $("#slidermenu").animate({
        right: animateToPosition
    }, 200);

});
```

I made a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gohze4wk/1/). If you are going with the `css` solution, it's fine. Maybe this will help someone else in the future.