# Button that displays/hides highlighted url below it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been looking for a button that on click displays a highlighted URL below/besides it and hides it again when pressed again. I recall seeing one before but I have no idea where it was and can't find any examples of it.

I did find [Button that displays and hides a sliding menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27038779/button-that-displays-and-hides-a-sliding-menu) but it wasn't quite what I was looking for and I'm not experienced enough to apply that code to make something similar but with a textbox proper formatted below the button.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show
If you want to preserve the space where the text gets hidden or not, I suggest you read up on css styling.

Comment: Thanks, that'll help me get further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through the below code you are looking for.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var btnA = $("#btnSubmit");
  btnA.click(function () {
     $("#url").toggle();
  });
});
```

The JSFiddle for same is as below.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Law05rLL/)

Do let me know if that doesn't help.

Comment: Previous solutions had already helped me but This is pretty much exactly what I was after(besides the highlighting). This should do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery's Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) might just be what you are looking for.

A basic example to obtain what you want except highlighting could be

```
<button onclick="$('#URL').toggle();">Click Me</button>
<br />
<span id="URL">www.google.com</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @CarstenFarving This looks more like a comment

Answer (score 0):

Or depending of the case, you could just do it with checkbox element and some css.

[example](http://codepen.io/villekoo/pen/YyNRBZ)

```
<label for="your-btn">
<input type="checkbox" value="" name="" id="your-btn"> 
<span>Button</span>
</label>

<style>
[type="checkbox"] {
border: 0; 
clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
height: 1px; margin: -1px; 
overflow: hidden; 
padding: 0; 
position: absolute; 
width: 1px;
}

[type="checkbox"] + span {
color: white;
background: #333;
line-height: 1.5;
padding: 1em;
display: inline-block;
width: auto;
cursor: pointer;
}

[type="checkbox"] + span::after {
content:'yourcontent';
padding-left: 2em;
position: absolute;
background: none;
color: black;
display: none;
}


[type="checkbox"]:checked + span {
 background: green;
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked + span::after {
 display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```